# Spring Web Flow 2.4.1 and Spring Security 4.0.1

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflow

We used Spring Web Flow 2.4.1 and Spring Security 3.x(up to 3.2.6) in our project. However after we've upgraded to Spring Security 4.0.1 we got the following exception. Any help?

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased: method <init>()V not found
at org.springframework.webflow.security.SecurityFlowExecutionListener.decide(SecurityFlowExecutionListener.java:102)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

****** **UPDATED ANSWER** *******

SWF 2.4.2 is available now spring.io/blog/2015/09/01/spring-web-flow-2-4-2-released

will fix this issue.

–Neil McGuigan

****** **OLD ANSWER** *******

for: `import org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased`

AffirmativeBased()
Deprecated. 
Use constructor which takes voter list

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/vote/AffirmativeBased.html

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/vote/AffirmativeBased.html

That AffirmativeBased() empty constructor has been deleted in the newer Spring Security 4.0.1 (it was already marked as deprecated in 3.2.6)

```
org.springframework.webflow.security.SecurityFlowExecutionListener.decide(SecurityFlowExecutionListener.java:102)
```

SecurityFlowExectionListener#decide method calls this empty constructor on line 102.

**Short answer:** Spring Webflow 2.4.1 wasn't updated for Spring Security 4.0.1 revert back to 3.2.6

**Long (shot) answer:** If you cannot revert and wish to continue to use webflow... This might be a long shot try extending org.springframework.webflow.security.SecurityFlowExecutionListener and @Override the decide method. Copy paste the original code of the decide method but change line 102 from

```
            abstractAccessDecisionManager = new AffirmativeBased();
```

to

```
            abstractAccessDecisionManager = new AffirmativeBased(voters);
```

Although this might fix your current issue... I suspect this will reveal further incompatibility issues but I think the change is trivial enough and is worth a shot.

Comment: Thank you, Airduster. Are there any plans to update Spring Web Flow? Since it's integrated with Spring Security it might be a good idea. Otherwise people cannot upgrade to newer version.

Comment: I inherited SecurityFlowExecutionListener overriding the decide method and everything worked fine.

Comment: @Sergey good to hear, if possible try to create a pull request for this 'bug'. I am not sure the project's pulse is weak on github but many still use it I suspect they will eventually it just just a low priority but moving forward don't start using webflow in NEW projects till we see a confirmation.

Comment: @Sergey https://jira.spring.io/browse/SWF-1657 looks like there is already a bug filed for it

Comment: SWF-1657 is now fixed, so spring webflow 2.4.2 (when released) will probably solve your problem

Comment: 2.4.2 is available now https://spring.io/blog/2015/09/01/spring-web-flow-2-4-2-released